# How to pass dynamic limit value for JPA View entity?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have created a view in MySQL and that view I am using in JPA as entity,

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "my_view")
```

Now the issue I am facing is I am trying to do pagination by setting the setMaxResults in the the query object, in the backend what is happening is the view is not having a limit so its trying to fetch all the records, then its applying the setMaxResults, which is killing the performance I could have written the native query but it was bit messy.

Gernerated query will look as follows

```
select e from myViewEntity where 1=1 and (adding addition constraints as parameter)
```

My Question is there any way I can pass Limit as dynamic value to the view ??

> Note: I am passing constraints to the view by using alias name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` methods in query like below by passing the value for firstResult and maxResults dynamically.

```
List<User> users = entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM User o", User.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
```

Comment: I think you missed this point,in the backend what is happening is, the view is not having a limit so its trying to fetch all the records, then its applying the setMaxResults